# If $f:[a, b]\to \mathbb{R}^3$, $f(x)= (f_1(x),f_2(x),-1)$ so set $f([a, b])$ has Jordan measure $0$, is it enough for $f$ to be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Exactly,my problem looks like:

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be continuous and $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x),-1)$. Prove that $f([a,b])$ has Jordan measure zero.

I thought that I can't prove it if I don't have that $f$ is integrable (I need that for Lipschitz condition).

Am I right or I can prove it even with the condition that $f$ is only continuous?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For some large $M,$

$$f([a,b])\subset [-M,M]\times [-M,M]\times [-1,-1].$$

Comment: Does this mean that I have to have the condition that f is integrable? Thank you

Comment: $f$ integrable? I don't see why that would be relevant.

Comment: It's ok now.I thought that I should prove this using Lipschitz.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is bounded; say $|f(x)|\le M$ for $x\in[a,b]$. Hence $$f([a,b])\subset [-M,M]^{2}\times[-1-\epsilon,-1+\epsilon]$$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Does this mean that f doesn't have to be integrable or it does?

Comment: Why do I have that f is bounded?

Comment: @Tota Calculus: Any continuous function on $[a,b]$ is bounded.

Comment: yes,understood.And the set in the right side that you wrote has Jordan measure 0,so that I can prove this without having f integrable,right?

Comment: @Tota No, the Jordan measure of the set on the right is $4M^2\epsilon$.

Comment: ah,yes.Thank you.

Comment: Looks like $8M^2\epsilon$ to me.